# What is the inet_addr function equivalent in C#

Tags: c++, c#-3.0, types, wrapper

i need to know how to use an IP address like inet_addr("192.168.0.2"); in C++
where this returns DWORD. My wrapper in C# treats this field as an Int?

Can anyone help on this misunderstanding?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? C# already has wrappers around the entire IP stack -- you shouldn't need to be P/Invoking those.

Comment: I have a wrapper in a C++ library, i just read the documentation to use the library, but the examples are in C++ code, which i dont understand quite enough in some places. On place is this while setting an IP Address to a DWORD type field where my wrapper has as int field. So i wonder how to convert the IP Address string (etc. "192.168.0.2") and set it to the int field.

Comment: It might help your question if you showed us the C++ code and the C# code where you're stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the IPAddress class.  It will hassle you a bit because it tries to prevent you from taking a dependency on IP4 addresses.  The Address member is declared obsolete.  Here is the workaround:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var addr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.2");
        int ip4 = BitConverter.ToInt32((addr.GetAddressBytes()), 0);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X8}", ip4);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: 0200A8C0

Note that the address is in proper network order (big endian).

Answer (score 0):

Well if it .net I assume its a little endian machine so you "could" do it as follows:

```
address = (192 << 0) | (168 << 8) | (0 << 16) | (2 << 24);
```

I'm pretty sure thats the right way round :)